# Android application startup sequence

Tags: android

I am working on an app where I need to bind to a database via IBinder.  I planned on putting any framework initialization in my Application subclass since that kind of stuff isn't presentation related and I know that the Application will be instantiated once per app.

```
 public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      // Bind to the db server
      Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DB.BIND_ADDRESS);
        super.bindService(intent,
          new ServiceConnection() {
          @Override
          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
                                         IBinder service) {
            DB.start(service);
          }
          @Override
          public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            DB.shutdown();
          }
        },
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
      );
  }
}
```

The problem that I run into is that the call back to my ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() isn't performed until my activity has started and that's a problem since I need the database available for the activity to display the data.  I currently see this behavior.

```
myApplication.onCreate()
myActivity.onCreate()
myActivity.onStart()
serviceConnection.onServiceConnected()
```

This is a problem since the database isn't yet connected when the onStart() is invoked on my activity.

I would rather not have to move this infrastructure initialization in the activities.  So I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to block the application.onCreate to wait until
   the onServiceConnected() has been invoked?  This being single
   threaded I don't see how.
2. Is there a way to tell android not to invoke any onStart() on any
   activities prior to my application having completed its
   initialization such that I have the following startup sequence

This

```
myApplication.onCreate()
serviceConnection.onServiceConnected()
myActivity.onCreate()
myActivity.onStart()
```

or

```
myApplication.onCreate()
myActivity.onCreate()
serviceConnection.onServiceConnected()
myActivity.onStart()
```

Comment: what you want to achieve with this ?

Comment: I want for my infrastructure initialization to be complete before the activities' onStart are invoked.

Comment: I got your point.

Comment: *the Application will be instantiated once per app* – note that for a multi-process app the Application class will be created for each process.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rewrite your code to work with the Android framework.  There is no way to wait in onCreate-  all the code happens on a single thread, it won't even attempt to start your service until onCreate is finished.  I suggest you use onResume or onServiceCreated itself to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do like that.The best solution is to show some type of loading dialog until it connected and fetch from the database